# How to correctly comment tags on HTML?

Tags: html

Let's imagine we got this html:

```
<p>some text</p>
```

I have always comented like this:

```
<!--p>some text</p-->
```

And my co-worker says that's the right way to comment on html:

```
<!--<p>some text</p>-->
```

Is not valid the way I comment? Is one way more correct than the other?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Both comments will work because HTML just don't give a damn what's in between. You guys over there should talk over what's best for you and you only.

Comment: I have never seen your method of including the comment tags in other HTML elements' tags. But, as long as comments are like `<!-- -->`, it will work regardless of what's between them. (The exception to this is if you have other comment tags between them.) However, consider that it might make make your code a little less readable/maintainable to use unusual methods of commenting code.

Comment: dont use comments. [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779926/is-it-possible-to-make-xss-attacks-through-html-comments-with-jsp-code-inside)

Comment: I don't think `<p>some text</p>` exposes any security risks.

Comment: @csaw ...you mean, don't use exploitable code in comments.

Comment: I do this trick where I sometimes disable a comment by just removing a single - or the > from the closing bit, like this <!-- --, it's fast and helpful for testing markup so I'll go for the 2nd option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is not valid the way I comment?

It is valid.

> Is one way more correct than the other?

Your method is not traditional. Instead of commenting out the code, you are effectively deleting the first and last characters while adding comments.

Answer (score 0):

everything between

`<!-- -->`

will be treated as a comment, so both are valid

Answer (score -1):

Both would be valid HTML comments. It's a matter of taste, but I've never seen your variant before.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is.. The valid way is `<!-- Text Here -->`, so doing `<!-- <p>Comment</p> -->` will remove the paragraph element and treat it as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Comments consist of the following parts, in exactly the following order:

the comment start delimiter "`<!--`"
text
the comment end delimiter "`-->`"
The text part of comments has the following restrictions:

must not start with a "`>`" character
must not start with the string "`->`"
must not contain the string "`--`"
must not end with a "`-`" character

According to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#comments).