# Does JSF Morjarra 2.1.3 prevent CSRF attacks?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, csrf-protection

I seem to get mixed messages researching on the web.  And after reading this: [How JSF 2.0 prevents CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704612/how-jsf-2-0-prevents-csrf)

Seems like there there is one level of CSRF protection in JSF2.0 & 2.1 (web.xml only)

Seems like there are two levels of CSRF protection with JSF2.2.  (web.xml and faces-config change)

For JSF2.x I could add this to web.xml.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

or use the default this to web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**My question is does Morjarra 2.1.3 prevent CSRF attacks using one of these two settings (which one)?**

I understand with JSF 2.2 CSRF can be more explicit with this setting by adding the following code to the faces-config.xml file:

```
<protected-views>
    <url-pattern>/csrf_protected_page.xhtml</url-pattern>
</protected-views>
```

Comment: `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` context param exists since JSF 2.0, not from JSF 2.2. And yes, it will do regardless the param value. You have to re read BalusC answer in that question.