# When I submit an jsf form the application show a 403 error page. Why this?

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, spring-security, primefaces, csrf

I programming an Spring boot application with JSF using [Joinfaces](http://joinfaces.org) and [primefaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/getstarted.xhtml).
I wrote the registration form and I tested it.
When i send the form with POST method the application get me a 403 error.
How can I solve this problem?

JSF template of my signup page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view>


    <h:head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mystyle.css"></link>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h2>
            <h:outputText value="{msg.translate('male')}"/>

        </h2>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="card-header-title">
                        <div><img width="100" height="50" src="it-it/assets/images/l1.svg"> </img></div>
                        <p>Crea il tuo account Firenet</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h:form >
                        <div class="inputs-row-container">

            <span class="ui-float-label group-first-item">
       <p:inputText id="firstname" value="" style="width: 100%" required="true"/>
                <p:message for="firstname" />
       <p:outputLabel for="@previous" value="{msg.translate('signup-form.input.firstname.label')}"/>
   </span>
                            <span class="ui-float-label">
       <p:inputText value="" style="width: 100%"/>
       <p:outputLabel for="@previous" value="{msg.translate('signup-form.input.lastname.label')}"/>
   </span>


                        </div>


                        <span class="ui-float-label group-item">
                            <p:inputText id="emailInput" value="#{registrationStepOne.email}" style="width: 100%"  ></p:inputText>
       <p:outputLabel for="@previous" value="{msg.translate('signup-form.input.email.label')}"/>
   </span>
                        <h:message for="emailInput" style="color: red"/>



                        <div class="inputs-row-container">

            <span class="ui-float-label group-first-item">
       <p:inputText value="" style="width: 100%" required="true"/>
       <p:outputLabel for="@previous" value="{msg.translate('signup-form.input.password.label')}"/>
   </span>
                            <span class="ui-float-label">
       <p:inputText value="" style="width: 100%"/>
       <p:outputLabel for="@previous" value="{msg.translate('signup-form.input.repeatpassword.label')}"/>
   </span>


                        </div>




                        <p:commandButton action="/registration/secondstep.xhtml" value="Register" />
                    </h:form>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>


</f:view>
</html>
```

Java code for my JSF page:

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator;
import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.annotation.Join;
import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.el.ELBeanName;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;
import java.io.Serializable;


@Scope("session")
@Component(value = "registrationStepOne")
@ELBeanName(value="registrationStepOne")
@Join(path = "/signup/v1/webcreateaccount", to = "/registration/firststep.xhtml")
public class RegistrationStepOne implements Serializable {


    private String email;
    public RegistrationStepOne() {

        //  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale("it", "IT"));


    }
    public String save() {

        return "/registration/secondstep.xhtml";
    }
    // Validate Email
    public void validateEmail(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        String emailStr = (String) value;


        if (!EmailValidator.getInstance(false).isValid(emailStr)) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(new ResourceBundleBean().translate("signup-form.input.email.errors.email"));
            throw new ValidatorException(message);
        }
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Spring boot post request logs

```
  : Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of AnnotationConfigurationProvider: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.
2019-09-07 11:25:40.618 DEBUG 20204 --- [0.1-8083-exec-7] o.s.w.c.s.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport    : Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of ClassLoaderConfigurationProvider: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.
2019-09-07 11:25:40.618 DEBUG 20204 --- [0.1-8083-exec-7] o.s.w.c.s.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport    : Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of ContextSpecifiedConfigurationProvider: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.
2019-09-07 11:25:40.619 DEBUG 20204 --- [0.1-8083-exec-7] o.s.w.c.s.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport    : Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of DefaultXMLConfigurationProvider: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.
2019-09-07 11:25:40.622 DEBUG 20204 --- [0.1-8083-exec-7] o.s.w.c.s.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport    : Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of SpringBootBeanNameResolver: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.
2019-09-07 11:25:40.623 DEBUG 20204 --- [0.1-8083-exec-7] o.s.w.c.s.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport    : Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of DefaultBeanNameResolver: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.
2019-09-07 11:25:40.624 DEBUG 20204 --- [0.1-8083-exec-7] o.s.w.c.s.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport    : Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of FacesBeanNameResolver: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.
2019-09-07 11:25:40.624 DEBUG 20204 --- [0.1-8083-exec-7] o.s.w.c.s.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport    : Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of SpringBeanNameResolver: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.
2019-09-07 11:25:40.635  WARN 20204 --- [0.1-8083-exec-7] unknown.jul.logger                       : Cannot find classes folder: /WEB-INF/classes/
2019-09-07 11:25:40.644 DEBUG 20204 --- [0.1-8083-exec-7] o.s.w.c.s.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport    : Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of WebXmlServletRegistrationProvider: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.
2019-09-07 11:25:40.644 DEBUG 20204 --- [0.1-8083-exec-7] o.s.w.c.s.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport    : Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of Servlet3ServletRegistrationProvider: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.
2019-09-07 11:25:40.655 DEBUG 20204 --- [0.1-8083-exec-7] o.s.w.c.s.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport    : Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of ContextParamsPostProcessor: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.
2019-09-07 11:25:40.658 DEBUG 20204 --- [0.1-8083-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={masked}
```

Comment: I don't see any relation with JSF here. 403's are not something JSF normally produces. So better check your authentication framework...

Answer (score 2):

The error is probably due to [Spring CSRF protection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/csrf.html) .

If you enable debug logging for Spring security in application.properties
(`logging.level.org.springframework.security: debug`)
then you will see something like

```
2019-12-24 15:56:33,951   [99] DEBUG         o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter:doFilterInternal      127 - Invalid CSRF token found for <JSF page>
```

As JSF already has a built-in CSRF protection ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7725675/522578),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704612/how-jsf-2-0-prevents-csrf)) you can disable the Spring own CSRF protection via configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
    
    }
}
```

See also [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159772/jquery-post-giving-403-forbidden-error-in-spring-mvc).