# Do i have to use csrf protection in React SPA?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, csrf

I use React Single Page Application as a client side or Create React App (CRA).

In my backend i use Node.js & Express.

to fetch data or store i need to call API from client to backend.

actually I've seen there are several middleware like: - Express CSURF

but to be honest I don't understand how to send a CSRF token to the client every request. I have tried several times, by inserting the CSRF into a cookie and then taking it on the client side. but when the first request or new cookie is stored, I get error `Invalid CSRF Token`.

and even though I did this:

```
app.use(session({
    genid: function (req) {
        return uuidv4() // use UUIDs for session IDs
    },
    name:keys.session.name,
    secret: keys.session.secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    rolling:true,
    cookie: { 
        secure: false,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge:keys.session.maxAge, // satu hari,
        sameSite:true,
     }

}));
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(csrf({ cookie: false }));


app.use((req,res,next)=>{
     res.cookie('CSRF_token', req.csrfToken(), { sameSite: true });
})
```

Which means the CSRF_token cookie will change each request. but I only set it once like this : `axios.defaults.headers.common['csrf-token'] = csrf;` and the results its still work, which should not working.

**So do I need CSRF? or how to configure the correct one on  react SPA.**

Comment: I am interested to know an answer for this

Answer (score 11):

> So do I need CSRF?

As stated here: [Am I under risk of CSRF attacks in a POST form that doesn't require the user to be logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397952/1934402) I think you should still set it.

As for why it is not working for you, I assume it is because of the header name. You may check what [CSURF checks by default](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf#value).

> The default value is a function that reads the token from the following locations, in order:
>
> - req.body._csrf - typically generated by the body-parser module.
> - req.query._csrf - a built-in from Express.js to read from the URL query string.
> - req.headers['csrf-token'] - the CSRF-Token HTTP request header.
> - req.headers['xsrf-token'] - the XSRF-Token HTTP request header.
> - req.headers['x-csrf-token'] - the X-CSRF-Token HTTP request header.
> - req.headers['x-xsrf-token'] - the X-XSRF-Token HTTP request header.

Going by what CSURF checks, you have a variety of options to choose from, and looking at [axios, it seems to have a couple options for setting xsrf cookie and header names](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config).

```
...
// `xsrfCookieName` is the name of the cookie to use as a value for xsrf token
xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN', // default

// `xsrfHeaderName` is the name of the http header that carries the xsrf token value
xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN', // default
...
```

For example, in order to use the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header key axios comes with by default, I used the following method in my App.js file:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`/api/csrf`) // Send get request to get CSRF token once site is visited.
      .then(res => {
        axios.defaults.headers.post['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = res.data; // Set it in header for the rest of the axios requests.
      })
  }
```

You could, however, use a form hidden input or any other method you're comfortable with. You can read more about why it's common to put them in cookies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20504846/1934402).

I'm not sure what you're using for your client, but if you're using Redux, you may look [here](https://link.medium.com/pd3BxWdoZV) for help. If it doesn't work, you may Google other methods.

Comment: How safe is this? requesting the csrf token via an endpoint. Doesn't this defeat the purpose of a csrf token?

Comment: @alex067 Ideally you would have a frontend server to inject the token in your frontend app. You're correct in the sense that this isn't the best solution, but I haven't been able to find a way to mitigate this without a frontend server. Otherwise you can sign the token in a jwt cookie to make sure it wasn't replaced.

Comment: I've spent an entire day looking for a solution and I can't. No one appears to know how to do this properly.

Comment: > Make sure CSRF tokens can not be accessed with AJAX! Don't create a /csrf route just to grab a token, and especially don't support CORS on that route!

This approach is not recommended according to this [guide](https://github.com/pillarjs/understanding-csrf).